# Adding cells to table view (UITableView) in XCode

Tags: xcode, uitableview, cell

I'm new to X-Code and have just started working on my first app. I'm using Storyboards. To the Navigation Controller scene I've added a MasterViewController with two cells, which leads to two DetailViewControllers (Detail1 & Detail 2).

- Number of Columns = 1
- Number of rows in columns = 2

I've added a Reuse Indicator for the cells in the attributes inspector, and made the connection in the storyboard.

But when I run the app, I can only see the first cell x2.

When I look in the MasterViewController.m I can see the code for the first cell, but I don't understand how to insert the second cell etc!

I know the solution is easy and I've been looking for the answer for 3 days now, I feel stupid but I really need some help now,,

Can someone help me understand how to add more cells in the code, and maybe understand the Table View Code a bit more?

This is the code for the table view so far:

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return 2;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Formal";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

// Configure the cell...

return cell;
}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    // Delete the row from the data source
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath][withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}   
else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
    // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
}   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
return YES;
}
*/

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
/*
 <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
 // ...
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
 */
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets say you have an array called arr.

Then you have to return the number of objects in the array when numberOfRowsInSection gets called.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [arr count];
}
```

Your cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method should look like this to print out the strings in the array.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Formal";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell.

cell.textLabel.text = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This helped me a lot on the way, still took me some time to figure it all out but now I get it. :)

Comment: Sorry, Im new to this place as well.. I tried to, but I dont have enough reputation points to do it. Maybe I should have added the new info to your answer instead of posting it as a new answer. hmm

Comment: @KristofferBilek Dont worry about it. NP

Answer (score 0):

## My code now looks like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

omMeny = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//Add items
[omMeny addObject:@"Formålet med guiden"];
[omMeny addObject:@"Aromahjulet"];
[omMeny addObject:@"Fagterm"];


//Set the title
self.navigationItem.title = @"Om Rødvin";
}

//dealloc method declared in RootViewController.m
- (void)dealloc {

[omMeny release];
[super dealloc];
}


// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
// return 2;
return [omMeny count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Om";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Set up the cell...
NSString *cellValue = [omMeny objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

// Configure the cell...

return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
/*
 <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
 // ...
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
 */
}

@end
```

with this in the .h

```
@interface OmMasterViewController : UITableViewController {

NSMutableArray *omMeny;
}
```