# How to show a viewController for each cell created by user?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uitableview, uistoryboard

i am wondering how to make that if user adds a new cell in tableview, and when he select it it goes to a detailview, and if he add other cell, its go to other view and keep on. Summing, it gets a detailviewcontroller for each cell he creates.

Aother solution to my problem will be that when the user create a cell, what he writes in the detail is saved for this particular cell. Using a "prototype" detailview.

I was diggin a lot without any result, i am stuck days ago.

Im using excode 4.5, so i can do it with storyborda if its possible but i dont know how.

Thanks.

Sorry my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allow the user to add cells to the table view : [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866813/adding-cells-to-table-view-uitableview-in-xcode)

Then in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, when the user selects a row, load the same view each time. `MyDetailView`, but depending on which row was pressed, populate the detail view with certain data. Go watch [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QBrkavVJsw0) youtube tutorial it shows how to do this, and save it with core data.

Good luck :)

**EDIT**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];

    DetailView * detail = (DetailView *) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myDetailView"];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];//This makes the cell flash blue

    [self detail animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The above code will send the user to that detail view no matter what cell was pressed. So, an `if` isnt really necessary.

Comment: When implementating dis selectrowatindexpath should i use an if¿

Comment: You can, but for what you want, It isnt necessary. See my answer